# Restore Ubuntu to newly installed operating system

Tags: 12.04, restore

I want to restore my ubuntu 12.04 OS just as a fresh installed Ubuntu 12.04 operating system by restoring everything like factory defaults. Is it possible? How to do it from terminal as i am connected via ssh to the ubuntu system.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, actually restoring to true factory is VERY hard and involves too much work than people really want to do.

The best thing you can do is to just reinstall Ubuntu from the LiveCD.

Edit: You can probably uninstall (purge) all of your user-installed programs and remove your home files.

Comment: :( But I dont have the access to the UI. I am connected to the Ubuntu machine via ssh connection.